# LINKED LIST question C++ ...Can we make TWO different node types in one program?

Tags: c++

I have another project to finish off regarding linked lists.
I wanted to know if it was possible to write in TWO struct nodetype codes to create two nodes.
If so how and where should I place them?
My code is going to contain of one node type with "Videos" in a list.
And another node type with "Customer" details in a list.

I plan to use functions for every other operation I will enable for the program to do. I wanted to know the code for making two nodes and how and where I should specify these nodes when I make functions specifically for them?(such as inserting a new video for the video node and inserting a video for customer node(showing that they rented the video) etc etc)...

Can someone please explain the code's details so I can understand it?

Comment: Are you saying that you have implemented a Linked List, and would now like to enable it to hold different types?

Comment: I want to have two different node types in my program.One list should contain videos,and the other list should contain customers' details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an instantiation of a class template yields a new type, you can make your list node a template:

```
template<class Tag>
struct ListNode
{
    ListNode *prev, *next;
};
```

And then derive multiple times from the same template instantiating it with a different tag type:

```
struct VideoTag;
struct CustomerTag;

struct Item 
    : ListNode<VideoTag>
    , ListNode<CustomerTag> 
{};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T *data;
    Node<T> *next;
};
```

Then, your list heads would look like this:

```
Node<Videos> *videos;
Node<Customer> *customers;
```

Alternative is to use an opaque pointer (`void*`) as list data (and then cast into the proper type), but this is not type safe and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes I read it ...Does it mean that I make two nodes by just inputting one code and two heads?that's not exactly the same as making two nodes is it?

Comment: @Oli, @Piotr: I think Yuki needs to experience some of the pain associated with code duplication before trying to sell him on templates.

Comment: @Yuki, Ben is saying that templates are used to prevent code duplication, but until a programmer has experienced the pains that code duplicating can (and will) cause, the purpose behind templates is less obvious.

Comment: @Yuki: Imagine you have not just two of these lists, but 20.  And you find out they're too slow, so you decide to use a skiplist.  Now you have to do that 20 times, which is a little bit painful.  Then you find out you made a mistake in your skiplist implementation, so now you have to fix it 20 times, and test 20 fixes, and... quite a pain in the neck, really.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  You'll need a different name for each nodetype structure, and the next pointer in each will be its own type.  There's nothing magic about the name "node" or "nodetype", you can easily make a linked list using "videonode".

Also, you need to be more careful about distinguishing between "nodes" and "lists".  You said "I wanted to know the code for making two nodes" but that makes no sense.  Even one list already has two or more nodes, they're linked together.  Each list is represented by a pointer to the first node, but a list is conceptually more than just a node.

What you want is two lists, which hold different types.  All that requires is picking unique names for the nodetype structure and head pointer for each list.

Comment: I meant that i wanted a code for making two node types.Does that mean I have to write  the nodetype structure code twice for both node types?

Comment: @Yuki: You can, or you can use templates.  If you're never heard the word "template" before this question, you probably should just write the structure twice.  As you become experienced, you'll start using templates that other people have written, and then writing them yourself.